# UDP receive function throwing nullpointerexception

Tags: android, udp

I'm trying to send and receive simple UDP msg through wifi network. I am using the following code. My wifi network is working fine and i've initialized the socket variable Then also everytime i'm getting null pointer exception at receive method. Please help.

```
    public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             WifiConfiguration conf=new WifiConfiguration();
                String networkSSID="Lenovo S920";
                String pass="12345678saz";
                conf.SSID = "\"" + networkSSID + "\"";
                conf.preSharedKey = "\"" + pass + "\"";
                conf.status = WifiConfiguration.Status.ENABLED;        
                conf.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.TKIP);
                conf.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.CCMP);
                conf.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_PSK);
                conf.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.TKIP);
                conf.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.CCMP);
                conf.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.RSN);
            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
            try {
                serverSocketUDP.receive(packet);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            catch(NetworkOnMainThreadException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: How, where, when is the serverSocketUDP initialized? this is the relevant code that is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either:

1. 'serverSocketUDP' must be null
2. your description is incorrect, or
3. this isn't the real code.